# Find this indefinite integral $(x^2+25)^{{x^4/2}}$

Tags: integration

Find the integral
$\mspace{10mu}\int \frac{\sqrt{x^2+25}}{x^4}dx$.
I have no idea what to do...

Comment: Your expression in the title and in the question do not match.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:
Set $x=\dfrac1y,dx=-\dfrac{dy}{y^2}$

$$I=\int\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2+25}}{x^4}dx=-\int\dfrac{y^4\sqrt{1+25y^2}}{y^2|y|}dy$$

If $y<0,$  $$I=\int y\sqrt{1+25y^2}dy$$

Set $1+25y^2=u$

Answer (score 2):

Let $x=5\,\text{csch}\,\theta$. Then $dx=-5\,\text{csch}\,\theta\coth\theta d\theta$ and $\sqrt{x^2+25}=5\coth\theta$. Then
$$\begin{align}\int\frac{\sqrt{x^2+25}}{x^4}dx&=\int\frac{5\coth\theta\left(-5\,\text{csch}\,\theta\coth\theta d\theta\right)}{5^4\,\text{csch}^4\theta}=-\frac1{25}\int\cosh^2\theta\sinh\theta d\theta\\
&=-\frac1{75}\cosh^3\theta+C=-\frac1{75}\frac{(x^2+25)^{3/2}}{x^3}+C\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Move one of the $x$'s in to the square root from the $x^4$ in the denominator:

$$\int \frac{\sqrt{x^2+25}}{x^4}dx = \int \frac{\sqrt{1+\frac{25}{x^2}}}{x^3} dx = -\frac{1}{75}\left(1+\frac{25}{x^2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}+C$$

Comment: This manipulation is not valid if $x\lt0$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Use one of the substitutions:

1. $x=5\tan t$, $\enspace\mathrm dx=5(1+\tan^2t)\,\mathrm dt$,
2. $x=5\sinh t$, $\enspace\mathrm dx=5\cosh t \,\mathrm dt$,

and do some (hyperbolic) trigonometry to eliminate the square root.